# Left Nav menu missing in all SharePoint sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

The left nav menu disappeared from my SharePoint 2019 servers (2 Web Front Ends and 2 SQL Back Ends, all with the latest OS, SharePoint, and SQL patches) recently. I've tried the following:

1. Create a new Site Collection in the existing Web Application
2. Create a new web application and a new site collection within it

All show the same issue.

For reference, I've placed a screenshot below showing the blank left nav. To generate that screenshot, I created a new web application, created a new site collection in it (team site) and nothing else.

I welcome ideas as I am new to SharePoint 2019. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- If someone has access to this site, can they see the navigation?
- Do you get the same result if you try to access the site with a different browser?
  Please try opening the browser by running as administrator.
- If you still get the same result, make sure you have not set oslo as your site's master page and that you have "Enable fast startup" checked.

Reference: [Current Navigation Bar missing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e51c5de-a77b-4b3c-a674-49cf6ef022eb/current-navigation-bar-missing?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: hi, Is there any update on this thread?